# Table does not exist but still showing in 'sp_tables'

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005

When I run sp_tables '%sample%' am getting result with one row showing table name as "SampleData". But when I put that table in select statement am getting error message.

> Cannot find a table or object with the name "SampleData". Check the system catalog.

Am not able to select or drop that table. Even in object explorer I didn't find this table. Then how it is showing in sp_tables? I need to drop that table. How do I do it?

Comment: can you browse the table in sql management studio?

Answer (score 0):

Per the [sp_tables documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186250%28v=sql.90%29.aspx):

> Privilege information about the current user's read or write access to
>   a specific table is not always checked. Therefore access is not
>   guaranteed.

Is it possible that you do not have access to the table?

Comment: Am the admin. So I have access to all tables in DB. For all tables Table_Owner is dbo except this table. Is that the reason why am not able to select that table?

Comment: It depends on how permissions are set up and what you mean by "admin." E.g. you may only have full access to objects owned by dbo, and so you cannot access this other object. Try querying for permissions via `fn_my_permissions`: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176097(v=sql.90).aspx